How to get user following/follows working with SQLModel/FastAPI
Whenever I attempt to add/remove a follower to the User.following I get the error:
sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place?

I tried all the lazy type options but (select, selectin, dynamic, subquery, raise) and all throw the same MissingGreenlet exception. How do I get this to work?
MODELS (SQLModel)
class UserFollowLink(SQLModel, table=True):
    follower_id: int = Field(default=None, foreign_key="users.id", primary_key=True)
    followed_id: int = Field(default=None, foreign_key="users.id", primary_key=True)

class User(SQLModel, table=True)
    following: list["User"] = Relationship(
        back_populates="followers",
        link_model=UserFollowLink,
        sa_relationship_kwargs={
            "lazy": "selectin",
            "foreign_keys": "[UserFollowLink.follower_id]",
        },
    )
    followers: list["User"] = Relationship(
        back_populates="following",
        link_model=UserFollowLink,
        sa_relationship_kwargs={
            "lazy": "selectin",
            "foreign_keys": "[UserFollowLink.followed_id]",
        },
    )

ROUTES (FastAPI)
@router.get("/{user_id}/follow")
async def follow_user(db: DB, current_user: CurrentUser, user_id: int):
    user = await db.get(User, user_id)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, "User not found")
    current_user.following.append(user)
    db.add(current_user)
    await db.commit()
    return current_user

I tried all the lazy types. This is usually what causes these errors.
